# How can I Connect google sheets to SQL Server via SSL via appscript

Tags: sql-server, ssl, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

How can you securely transfer data from SQL Server (Intranet) to google appscript?

I have made the connection to the SQL Server Instance, but im afraid of someone pickup the raw data when traveling to google servers.

Any recomendation how to accomplish this.

Basically the appscript is querying our internal database successfully, we just need a kind of encrytion. we have tried to upload .csv files and gdrive and import data to sheets, but some how data always get corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct guide from Apps Script to do this. Try the [How to Encrypt your Gmail Messages with Google Docs](https://www.labnol.org/internet/encrypt-gmail/28191/?_ga=1.167798437.56864645.1491278180) from Armit Agarwal. See if you can also use [SJCL encryption library](https://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) in your situation.